# how separate json field in postgres and got the field

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm working with mongoDB, and I used a wrapper mongo/Postegres.
Now, I can find my tables and data.

I want to do some statistics but I can't reach objects that got json type in Postgres.

My problem is that I got all the object in json but I need to separate the fields.

I used this :

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE rents( _id NAME, status text, "from" json )
SERVER mongo_server
OPTIONS (database 'tr', collection 'rents');
```

The field "from" is an object.

I found something like this :

```
enter code here
```

but nothing happened

[image: and this is the error]

Comment: It seems that you have some [BSON](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson) specific types inside the `from` property (such as `ObjectId`, which is not a valid type within JSON). This mapping will never work.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

The error (why a screenshot??) means that the data are not in valid `json` format.

As a first step, you could define the column as type `text` instead of `json`. Then querying the foreign table will probably work, and you can see what is actually returned and why PostgreSQL thinks that this is not valid JSON.

Maybe you can create a view on top of the foreign table that converts the value to valid JSON for further processing.